# Uninstall and Remove Metasploit framework on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, frameworks, metasploit

I had serious problems with Metasploit since I installed it, so I want to uninstall it

I did try /opt/metasploit-framework/uninstall but it doesn't work

can you help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah I think the instructions are outdated.

Do this in Terminal instead:

```
cd /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
sudo ./msfremove
```

That should do the trick.

Good luck!

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: It's work @danieliversen package metasploit has removed thank you.

Comment: After entering the terminal script, it will ask you if you are sure you want to uninstall it. Type "Y" for yes, enter your password, and you will notice afterwards that everything within your metasploit folder will be removed, leaving only the folder behind.

Answer (score -3):

sudo apt remove metasploit-framework

Comment: Read the question, please. "on Mac OSX" is in the title; they're not on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).